# Moving cell data to respective row based on numbers in the data

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am naive to macros. I have data in column B with 500 rows of data. The data are image files names like (X0011@00.jpg, X0021@00.jpg, X0031@00.jpg, X0171@00.jpg, X0411@00.jpg). I want to move each data to specific rows based on criteria in the next column.

The criteria must be to find the number as mentioned below:

> If the data is X0011@00.jpg, the number 1 after X00 must move to row 1.
>
> If the data is X0021@00.jpg, the number 2 after X00 must move to row 2.
>
> If the data is X0031@00.jpg, the number 3 after X00 must move to row 3.
>
> If the data is X0131@00.jpg, the number 13 after X0 must move to row 13.
>
> If the data is X0151@00.jpg, the number 15 after X0 must move to row 15.
>
> If the data is X0411@00.jpg, the number 41 after X00 must move to row 41.

See below how my data is displayed in Column B and how I want it in Column C.

I appreciate if anyone can provide macro for this.

```
            Col B             Col C
Row1     X0011@00.jpg     X0011@00.jpg
Row2     X0021@00.jpg     X0021@00.jpg
Row3     X0041@00.jpg     
Row4     X0051@00.jpg     X0041@00.jpg
Row5     X0071@00.jpg     X0051@00.jpg
Row6     X0111@00.jpg     
Row7     X0121@00.jpg     X0071@00.jpg
Row8     X0141@00.jpg                 
Row9          
Row10         
Row11                     X0111@00.jpg
Row12                     X0121@00.jpg
Row13                     
Row14                     X0141@00.jpg
```

Thanks

Comment: use mid function as mid(B2;2;3). Then convert it to number. Then you will have the row numbers of each Picture in the C column. It should be easy to handle rest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple routine that will do exactly what you're asking. How it works is for each cell in Column B, we define our row as only the 3 digits after the X. Then we copy the value of the cell it came from to the cell in the corresponding row.

```
Sub PicToRow()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim picName As String
    Dim picRow As Integer
    Dim picRange As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set picRange = ws.Range("B1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    For Each myCell In picRange
        If myCell.Value <> "" Then
            picName = Replace(LCase(myCell.Text), "x", "") 'Remove the X
            picRow = CInt(Replace(picName, "1@00.jpg", "")) 'Remove the rest
            ws.Range("C" & picRow).Value = myCell.Value 'Copy data to new cell
        End If
    Next myCell 'do it again
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. But it shows error Type mismatch at picRow = CInt(Replace(picName, "1@00.jpg", "")) 'Remove the rest

Comment: Siraj, I edited the code to fix the issue. Alternatively you could also make the "x" a "X" and not include the `LCase()` but it doesn't matter, it's all the same. This code works for me. If I've answered your question could you mark this as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub justForYou()
Dim i As Integer
With ActiveSheet
For i = 2 To Range("B1000").End(3).Row
    .Cells(i, 3) = Mid(.Cells(i, 2), 2, 3)
    .Cells(i, 3).Copy
    .Cells(i, 3).PasteSpecial xlValues
    .Cells(i, 2).Copy
    .Cells(.Cells(i, 3).Value, 4).PasteSpecial
Next

End With
End Sub
```

Here is a simple solution for you.